# Comparing rows vs array elements postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, lateral-join

I have a table `A` with `n` rows (200+) and different numeric columns.
I have a table `B` with `m` rows (100K+) and a column called `multipliers`, which is of type array (`REAL[]`). For every row in `B`, this array's length is `n`, ie. a multiplier for every numeric variable in `A`. The array is sorted to match the alphabetical order of the `id` field in `A`

Table **`A`**

```
id | values_1 | values_2
---|----------|-------------
1  | 11.2     | 10.2
2  | 21.9     | 12.5
3  | 30.0     | 26.0
4  | 98.0     | 11.8
```

Table **`B`**

```
id      | multipliers
--------|-------------
dafcec  | {2,3,4,9}
nkjhbn  | {0,0,1,5}
ccseff  | {1,2,0,5}
ddeecc  | {0,0,0,1}
```

I need a query that returns the `SUM( multipliers * values_1 )`.

Like this:

```
b.id    | sum(b.multipliers*a.value_1)
--------|----------------------------------
dafcec  | 2*11.2 + 3*21.9 + 4*30.0 + 9*98.0
nkjhbn  | 0*11.2 + 0*21.9 + 1*30.0 + 5*98.0
ccseff  | 1*11.2 + 2*21.9 + 0*30.0 + 5*98.0
ddeecc  | 0*11.2 + 0*21.9 + 0*30.0 + 1*98.0
```

I have tried with different subquerys, `LATERAL` joins and `UNNEST`, but I can't get a working result.
Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the easiest, but I believe expensive way to sum array would be:

```
t=# with b as (select id,unnest(multipliers) u from b)
select distinct id, sum(u)over (partition by id) from b;
    id    | sum
----------+-----
 ccseff   |   8
 nkjhbn   |   6
 ddeecc   |   1
 dafcec   |  18
(4 rows)
```

and no fast alternative comes to my mind here...

further - If I get it right you want a cartesian product - all against all, then:

```
t=# with b as (select id,unnest(multipliers) u from b)
, ag as (select distinct id, sum(u)over (partition by id) from b)
select ag.sum * v1, a.id aid, ag.id idb
from ag
join a on true;
 ?column? | aid |   idb
----------+-----+----------
     89.6 |   1 | ccseff
    175.2 |   2 | ccseff
      240 |   3 | ccseff
      784 |   4 | ccseff
     67.2 |   1 | nkjhbn
    131.4 |   2 | nkjhbn
      180 |   3 | nkjhbn
      588 |   4 | nkjhbn
     11.2 |   1 | ddeecc
     21.9 |   2 | ddeecc
       30 |   3 | ddeecc
       98 |   4 | ddeecc
    201.6 |   1 | dafcec
    394.2 |   2 | dafcec
      540 |   3 | dafcec
     1764 |   4 | dafcec
(16 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I edited the question to give an overview of the solution I am looking to achieve. In the end I need one `b.id` per row and one result for `sum(b.multipliers * a.values_1)`. I hope the edit helps to clarify it!!

Comment: please accept and/or upvote if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
It just needs to pack the `values` into an array and unpack them so they are comparable. It worked for me. The `ORDER BY` makes sure the packing occurs in the desired order.

```
   SELECT id, SUM (field * multiplier) result FROM 
    (
    with c as (
        SELECT array_agg( values_1 ORDER BY name ASC) val1
        from A
    ) 

    , ag as (
        select
            distinct id,
            multipliers
        from B
        )

    SELECT
        ag.id, 
        unnest(c.val1) field,
        unnest(ag.multipliers) multiplier
    FROM
        c, ag
    ) s
GROUP BY id
```